# I want to replace part of a column value in a dataframe using values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a column where part of the column is to be replaced by a value from another column. 
For example I want to move from this:

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Identification\Customer</th> 
    <th>Target Customer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CustomerA\BFG\CustomerA-CCP\CustomerA-CSA</td>
    <td>CustomerA</td> 
    <td>CustomerB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to this

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Reference
</th>
    <th>Identification\Customer</th> 
    <th>Target Customer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Customer<a style="color:red;">B</a>\BFG\CustomerA-CCP\CustomerA-CSA</td>
    <td>CustomerA</td> 
    <td>CustomerB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I only want the initial value of CustomerA to be changed to CustomerB. The rest of the values should stay the same.

I thought this should work but I get all na in the column

```
data = [['CustomerA\\BFG\\CustomerA-CCP\\CustomerA-Agreement',  'CustomerA',    'CustomerB'],['CustomerC\\BFG\\CustomerC-CCP\\CustomerC-Agreement', 'CustomerC',    'CustomerD']] 

customerCollateral = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Reference', 'Identification\\Customer','Identification\\Parent']) 

customerCollateral['Reference2']=customerCollateral.apply(lambda x:x['Reference'].replace(x['Identification\\Customer'],x['Identification\\Parent'],n=1),axis=1)

print(customerCollateral)
```

however when I run the above I got this error.
TypeError: ('replace() takes no keyword arguments', 'occurred at index 0')

If I do not use n=1 ten all the values of CustomerA is replaced with CustomerB.

Comment: in replace you are providing the actual column references which is not acceptable, this is what error says,provode the output that you want like you provided `data`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear and could not figure out how to edit the original entry. I want the Reference column or In the above example Reference2 column to have this value: CustomerB\BFG\CustomerA-CCP\CustomerA-Agreement. only the first occurence of CustomerA is changed to CustomerB the rest of the CustomerA stays the same. Dataframe implementation of replace does not seem to have n=1 and this creates the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x['Reference']` is the object in question, since `x` is a Series and it's already queried by name. The object that is being called with `replace(...)` is `str`.

But, `str.replace` does not have a keyword `n`. See the docs here, the limit is defined by a third parameter, not a keyword parameter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

```
customerCollateral['Reference'] = customerCollateral['Identification\Parent'].str.cat(customerCollateral['Reference'].str.extract(r"(\\.*)"))
```

Just concat the strings that you want in the correct order. I extracted the part of the reference column that we wanted and added the id/parent column.